# SqlLite pcl on Xamarin forms - System.Exception: This is the 'bait'

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Sqlite with xamarin forms (and prism), following this [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/). In both Android and Portable projects I installed sqlite-net-pcl from nuget.
When creating a table, an exception occours (I put just the most relevant messages):

```
 The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception. 
 at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init ()
 System.Exception: This is the 'bait'.  You probably need to add one of the SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_* nuget packages to your platform project.
```

...but looking at the packages in the Android project, it seems I have already installed the "raw" package (they are dependency of sqlite-net-pcl), Here the full packages.config for the Android project:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Prism.Core" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Prism.Forms" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Prism.Unity.Forms" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.0.12" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.0.12" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.1.114" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
</packages>
```

And this is packages.config for the Portable project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Prism.Core" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Prism.Forms" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Prism.Unity.Forms" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.1.114" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the full `packages.config` for both your PCL and Android projects. Also, do a rebuild of the Android project and grab the build output. That might have some interesting info in it.

Comment: I added the packages.config into the question

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue and I can't. The sample code is available here: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Todo/. I would suggest removing the package and re-add it. If you continue to have an issue, upload the diagnostic build log or share a link to it (it's long).

Comment: I re-create the project from scratch. The problem is gone. Thanks